# How to create custom models and include that in .world file?

Tags: ros, include, world, dae, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to include a small box (static) object in a .world file that has a **picture** in it. (I have .launch and .world file that works fine) I am new to ros and gazebo. I am little bit confused with all the model files (.dae, .model, .urdf, etc). How can I create a small box shape with a picture in it and how to include that in a .world file? Do I need to create a model in blender or sketchup and export it to .dae? I don't have a clear idea of how .dae, .model, .urdf files works together.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220484/how-to-create-custom-models-and-include-that-in-.world-file-?/) by [Ananthakrishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24606/ananthakrishnan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

one procedure to create custom Gazebo models is the following:

1. create the dae file of the model. For this there
   are several ways. One way is to use
   sketchup to find a model of the
   object you need, then download it,
   adapt it a little bit with blender,
   and save it.
2. Once you have the
   proper dae file for your model, you
   need to create a series of files
   that define the model. You need to
   create the model.conf, the model.sdf
   and the meshes directory where to
   put your dae file.
3. Then you have
   to place those files in the
   ~/.gazebo/models directory in order
   to be able to use it in an sdf
   .world file.
4. Final step is to include the model in your world file

Because all that is a little confusing, we created a video showing how to do all the process. You can find the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP4sDyrRzpU

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1